# removing randomization of vector initialization for doc2vec

Tags: python, random, gensim, doc2vec

I am using a pre-trained doc2vec BOW model [(AP-news)](https://github.com/jhlau/doc2vec). I am doing the following:

```
import gensim.models as g 
start_alpha=0.01
infer_epoch=1000
model="\\apnews_dbow\\doc2vec.bin"
m = g.Doc2Vec.load(model)
text='this is a sample text'
vec=m.infer_vector(text,alpha=start_alpha, steps=infer_epoch)
```

But if I compute the vec again for the same text then I am getting a different vector representation of the same text. Why is this happening and how can I aviod this. I want to have the same vector returned if I give exactly the same text. 
I tried following [this post](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/447) but does not seem to help.

Comment: You could probably do `np.random.seed(42)` so that every time the initialisation is the same?

Comment: where should I use this command?

Comment: Just after you import gensim.models. Make sure you `import numpy as np` first.

Comment: I do that but it still give different vector values for the same text..

Answer (score 5):

As described in the [Gensim project Github issue for deterministic inference](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/447), it should be sufficient to re-`seed()` the specific random-number generator used inside the model *every time* before you attempt inference. (The comment suggestion by @Coldspeed is the right general idea, but the Doc2Vec model uses its own `random` instance, rather than the `numpy` global one.)

That is, everywhere you have a line like your...

```
vec=m.infer_vector(text,alpha=start_alpha, steps=infer_epoch)
```

...you will need to precede that `infer_vector()` with a forced re-`seed()` of the model's random-generator:

```
m.random.seed(0)
```

Only then will the following `infer_vector()` use an equivalent sequence of random-numbers. (And if the same model is being used by multiple threads, all bets are off, because the PRNG could be advanced by other threads between seeding and use.)

Even though this should work, it's not a great idea to rely upon it. The algorithm behind most modes of Doc2Vec (and Word2Vec) includes inherent randomness, and each vector is just the result of a progressive approximation process that settles on a 'good enough' vector, subject to not just that inherent randomness, but all other parameters. Evaluations should be robust to small jitter in results, to respect the intrinsic variance of the model.

See related discussion in the Gensim FAQ: "[Q12: I've used Doc2Vec infer_vector() on a single text, but the resulting vector is different each time. Is there a bug or have I made a mistake? (doc2vec inference non-determinism)](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/recipes-&-faq#q12-ive-used-doc2vec-infer_vector-on-a-single-text-but-the-resulting-vector-is-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-doc2vec-inference-non-determinism)"

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset the seed every time before calling m.infer_vector(), as @gojomo already pointed out.

If you don't want to hardcode your seed you can do this:

```
m.random.seed(m.seed)
vec=m.infer_vector(text,alpha=start_alpha, steps=infer_epoch)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to removing randomization of vector initialization for doc2vec
, use should set `workers=1` in Doc2Vec and fix PYTHONHASHSEED by following code.

```
import os
import sys
hashseed = os.getenv('PYTHONHASHSEED')
if not hashseed:
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
    os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```